# Can I use stellar manipulation to destroy and re-create planets to get a favourable atmosphere type?

Tags: space-empires-4

In Space Empires IV the **Tectonic Bomb** can be used to destroy a planet, in which case it becomes an asteroid field. The **Matter Gravity Sphere** can be used to create a planet out of an asteroid field, which receives a random atmosphere and planet type (Gas Giant, Rock or Ice).

Can I use these two components to destroy and then re-create planets to make them more productive? For example, turning a moon with no atmosphere into a small planet with a breathable atmosphere.

Assuming I remove all my population from the planet before hand, are there any other downsides? Will it impact the happiness levels of any of my planets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Space Empires Wiki](http://wiki.spaceempires.net/index.php/Stellar_Manipulation_(SEIV)):

> A created planet will have a random atmosphere and type and there is no way to influence what kind of planet will be created.

So, yeah, you *can* just continually destroy and recreate until you get a more favorable atmosphere.  The biggest downside is the loss of all facilities on the planet; you'll need to spend the resources to build them all back up again, not to mention the amount of repairing and supplies needed to keep breaking and recreating the planet.

There is a happiness loss when losing a planet, but it seems to be specific to losing it to another empire.  It may not be applied when breaking it up yourself.  If it is, though, you're going to be losing 5% every time you destroy one of your colonized worlds.  This will happen once per planet you destroy, assuming you don't recolonize it in the meantime.

A better bet might be to just build an Atmospheric Modification Plant.  That takes 2-3 years to convert, but will have a more reliable effect, without the possible happiness hit.

Comment: Funny this tactic is available.  I do this in Master of Orion 2.